# IE11 font loading issue

Tags: internet-explorer-11, font-face

I'm having problems with some fonts not loading in IE11. I've added different font files for the Helvetica Neue Bold but still it's not loading on IE11 and there's no error in the console but for the SourceSansPro it loads with no problem. Any ideas why? Thanks!

[Font Face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzt8J.png)

[Source Sans Pro Loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP70q.png)

Comment: Haven't looked too closely yet, but I wouldn't put much stock in the SourceSansPro loading. Unless you've verified that it downloads and uses the specified font in-browser. If you're simply looking at it to see the font's loaded, it could be getting it from the systemwide fonts path.

Comment: Hi,I've added a new image that shows that the Source Sans fonts are loaded.